# Can I use my username to Log In rather than my email?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can't seem to use my profile name to log in, instead I have to use my email every time. Would it possible to log in using my username?

Answer (score 7):

You must log in with your email address if you have a Mojang account.

Comment: I think it might be back to Alpha Days, i always log in via my Username and not my email and i brought the game when it was in Alpha, that said i've never logged via my email

Comment: That could very well be the case, I didn't play Minecraft during Alpha so I only remember having to use my Email only(I started playing at 1.5)

Comment: There was an update when all the new accounts became Mojang accounts and that became the login.

Comment: @JeffreyLin beat me to it, i was just reading [here](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/928638), back in Alpha Days there wasn't a Mojang Account, just Minecraft

Answer (score 2):

If you purchased Minecraft before July 2012 you can use your username.
If you have, it is recommended that you migrate it into a Mojang account.

If you made your account after that date, you must use your email address to log in.

Comment: they actually force you to update your account to the email login method. I encountered this after I hadn't played since 1.6 and tried to log into the 1.8 client. It wouldn't let me log in until I went on minecraft.net and updated my account information.